# Barcode scanner hitting enter before all of the text is registered. Ipad/iphone only

Tags: ios, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have a barcode scanner on a web page that is scanning in 5-10 digits and hitting enter. The enter is part of the barcode scanner, where it hits enter after a scan. I see all of the numbers show up in the text field, but the process that runs on enter only receives most of them, missing the last one or two. Not every time, but about half of the time.

It seems like its hitting enter too quickly. We've upped and lowered the delay to every setting possible but it doesn't change anything. On Desktop it works totally fine 100% of the time.

is there anything I can do to help prevent this?

**Edit: Here is a snippet of the code.** I'm actually returning the code in a super weird way so this might not be valid, but it should maybe get you the idea.

The onclick event seems to be firing before the barcode has entered the full text. You can SEE the full text on the screen but it doesn't receive it. Ipad and iPhone only, and the Dolphin browser on both seems to work.

```
<div class="seven columns" style="margin-top:3px">
  <input type="text" name="txtCalculatedIdentifer" id="txtCalculatedIdentifier" data-name="CalculatedIdentifier" />
</div>
<div class="two columns">
  <input type="submit" class="okbutton modalsavebutton" name="btnCalculatedIdentifier" data-savespid="123"
                    onclick="return RunProcess(x) ? $('#txtCalculatedIdentifier').val() : $(' #txtCalculatedIdentifier').val())}, ScanInSave) ">
</div>
```

Comment: Is this on a web view inside an app?

Comment: It is hard to help you out with out some code for more context. There is a lot that could be going wrong. Post what you have and then we could try and do some debugging.

Comment: I've added some code, it was difficult to pull out, and really copy paste since I'm not a web guy.